# Efficient matrix / array generation

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, expression-construction

What is the most efficient way of generating the following matrix?

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & \dots\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \dots\\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \dots\\
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
\frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & 0 & \dots\\
\frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & \dots\\
\frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & \dots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\\
\end{array}
\right)$

where the first line begins $\{1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0\dots\}$

The second: $\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0,0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0,0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},0,0\dots\}$

The third: $\{\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},0,0,0,\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},0,0,0\dots\}$

and so on.

My effort is

```
y = 14; m = 7;
Table[Take[Drop[Take[Flatten[ConstantArray[Flatten[Riffle[Array[0 &, {n, n}], 
Array[1 &, {n, n}]]], y - n]], y], n], y - m]/n, {n, 1, m}] // MatrixForm
```

but calculates too many unnecessary terms.

Comment: Adding at least some minimal description of *what* it is you're trying to do (e.g. the "rules" for elements), instead of having readers decode it, might elicit more response.

Comment: Apologies - updated.

Comment: No worries, it just helps the reader to be clear on intent (like: "Is that pattern *really* the pattern...") without having to figure out the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should be pretty efficient (still generates a few extra elements, but I'd venture the overhead of short-circuiting that would exceed the overhead of the trimming):

```
y = 14; m = 7;

array=Take[Flatten[ConstantArray[#, Ceiling[(y - m)/Length@#]]], y - m] & /@
           Table[Join[ConstantArray[1/row, row], ConstantArray[0, row]], {row, 1, m}];

array//MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Much more efficient - thank you :)

Comment: @martin: My pleasure. On a quick y = 500; m = 250; test, it was over 1500X faster, and of course *much* more frugal on memory...

Comment: My one shut down the kernel at y=1000; m=500 !! :( - Much better! many thanks!!

Comment: @martin: Yep, that would eat memory pretty quickly using the method you posted. I just did a 5000 x 2500 *on a netbook* so little RAM, and no issues, took about a second (so ~0.1 sec on a "real" machine). Thanks for the accept!

Comment: Thanks for your help - it has made things much easier!! :)

Comment: Incredibly fast, as usual. :)

Answer (score 9):

Different approach:

```
SparseArray[{i_, j_} :> 1/i /; Mod[j, 2 i, 1] <= i, {7, 7}];
```

Not so fast but short.

```
MatrixForm @ %
```

> [image]

Comment: Very concise - doesn't seem to work for me though ...

Comment: @martin what do you mean? :)

Comment: Ah ... whoops !! :)

Comment: FYI: you don't need `Normal` before applying `MatrixForm`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I must admit I was to lazy to correct this :p

Answer (score 6):

On my machine this is about twice as fast as rasher's present code:

```
f[n_Integer] :=
 With[{split = Quotient[n, 2]},
   Join[
     Array[PadRight[#, n, #] &[Join @@ (ConstantArray[{1/#, 0}, #]\[Transpose])] &, split],
     LowerTriangularize[ConstantArray[1/Range[split + 1, n], n]\[Transpose], split]
   ]
 ]

f[9] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
 \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} \\
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{3} \\
 \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} \\
 \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & \frac{1}{5} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & \frac{1}{6} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & \frac{1}{7} & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & \frac{1}{8} & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{1}{9}
\end{array}
\right)$

The optimization is to recognize that everything in the bottom half of the array is equivalent to a simpler form easily produced with [`LowerTriangularize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LowerTriangularize.html), and only the top half is generated by a slower cyclic method.

This simpler form is approximately equivalent to rasher code in performance, and a bit more terse:

```
f2[n_Integer] :=
  Array[PadRight[#, n, #] &[Join @@ (ConstantArray[{1/#, 0}, #]\[Transpose])] &, n]
```

The simpler function updated to allow generation of different shapes of arrays:

```
f2[n_, m_] := 
  Array[PadRight[#, n, #] &[Join @@ (ConstantArray[{1/#, 0}, #]\[Transpose])] &, m]
```

I'm too tired to extend `f` likewise at the moment.

Comment: Wow - super-fast!! :)

Comment: Great code - thank you :)

Comment: @martin You're welcome.  Let me know if you discover anything wrong with it.

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard, Will do :)

Comment: Interesting: only slightly faster when generating a square matrix, considerably slower to get to row-subsets (as OP example). +1 in any case!

Comment: @rasher Only slightly, eh?  Version differences I guess.  I'll have to try harder!  I don't understand what you mean by row-subsets, and I didn't understand the need for both `m` and `y` so apparently I'm missing something.  Help?

Comment: @rasher Regarding version differences would you check the speed of this?: `f3[n_] := PadRight[#, {n, n}, #] & @ MapIndexed[ Take[#, Min[2 #2, n]] &, LowerTriangularize[ConstantArray[1/Range[n], n]\[Transpose]] ]`  It's slower on my system but perhaps it's competitive on yours?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Well, I assumed (oh, that could be a problem...) the two values were specified by the OP for a reason, otherwise if only square matrix is needed, there are faster ways (like yours, e.g.). Otherwise, getting to the form shown in the OP with yours means generating more than needed, then trimming: on a y = 5000; m = 1000; test (a 1kX4k result), your first is ~6X slower. On a y=2000, m=1000 test (a 1kX1k square result), yours is ~20% faster (on the loungebook caveat). Update: Tested second per your request, slower than your first on my test also.